# PHP Notice: Undefined property: User::$db and Call to a member function prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm really struggling to figure this out. I'm trying to learn how to do a role based access control from this website: https://sevvlor.com/post/2014/10/14/how-to-make-role-based-access-control-in-php/

I keep getting stuck with:

PHP Notice:  Undefined property: User::$db as non static in ... line 21

and

Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ... Line 21

Here is the entire code so far:

```
include "database.php";
class User 
 {
private $userRoles = array();
private static $db;

//Alternatively use your own way of setting your Database connection.
public static function setDatabase($db)
{
    self::$db = $db;
}

//Populate the user object when it's created
public function __construct($user_id)
{
    $getUser = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id = :userid ");
    $getUser->execute(array(":userid" => $userid));
    if($getUser->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        $userData = $getUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->fnamename = ucfirst($userData['fname']);
        $this->email = $userData['email'];
        //etc.. More data if needed
        self::loadRoles();//Initiate the userroles
    }
}

//Fill the array with this user's roles, it's
protected static function loadRoles()
{
    $fetchRoles = $this->db->prepare("SELECT user_role.role_id, role.role_name FROM user_role JOIN role ON user_role.role_id = role.role_id WHERE user_role.user_id = :user_id");
    $fetchRoles->execute(array(":user_id" => $this->user_id));

    //Populate the array
    while($row = $fetchRoles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $this->userRoles[$row["role_name"]] = Role::getRolePermissions($row["role_id"]);
    }
}

//Check if the user has a certain permission
public function hasPermission($permission)
{
    //If the user has more roles, check them too
    foreach ($this->userRoles as $role)
    {
        //Do the actual checking
        if ($role->hasPermission($permission))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
$userid = 1;
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};database={$dbname}", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$test = new User(1);
```

Database.php contains the correct credentials for the PDO connection statement. I did echo them to verify.

I know I'm new to this, but I thought I could figure this out!

Comment: You never called `User::setDatabase()`, so `$this->db` is not set. And since it's a static property, you should use `self::$db`, not `$this->db`.

Comment: You need to learn to walk before you can run. Go read a tutorial on object-oriented programming in PHP.

Comment: OK, thanks for that @Barmar ! That was what I was getting hung up on. I appreciate your help for sure. I've been reading tutorials all day, so I'm probably just stuck on something stupid since I've been getting frustrated for the last 2 hours! I think I'm up and running with this tutorial now!